# Why does the same SimpleDateFormat *sometimes* return a bad date?

Tags: java, date

OK - my first StackOverflow post: I hope it's not too ridiculous.  I'm trying to do something pretty basic: take two similarly-formatted Strings, convert them to Dates with the same SimpleDateFormat and then see the difference as a long. Posting the entire source here:

```
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.ParsePosition;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

public class DateCompare {
public static void main(String[] args){
    DateCompare dc = new DateCompare();
    try {
        long diff = dc.compare("2012-03-15T10:00:00.0Z",
                               "2012-03-15T10:44:56.1031157730031Z");
        System.out.println("Difference: "+diff);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
private long compare(String first,String second) throws ParseException{
    System.out.println(first);
    System.out.println(second);
    Date firstDate = datify(first);
    System.out.println(firstDate.toString());
    Date nextDate = datify(second);
    System.out.println(nextDate.toString());
    return(compare(firstDate,nextDate));
}
private Date datify(String in){
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSSSSSSSSSSS'Z'");
    Date theDate = sdf.parse(in,new ParsePosition(0));
    return(theDate);
}
private long compare(Date first,Date second){
    long diff=0;
    if (first.after(second)){
        diff = first.getTime()-second.getTime();
    }
    else{
        diff = second.getTime()-first.getTime();
    }
    return(diff);
}
}
```

and the results:

> 2012-03-15T10:00:00.0Z
>
> 2012-03-15T10:44:56.1031157730031Z
>
> Thu Mar 15 10:00:00 EDT 2012
>
> Mon Mar 19 16:17:54 EDT 2012
>
> Difference: 368274991

Makes no sense to me; any clues would be a huge help...

Comment: It's parsing it as `1031157730031` milliseconds.

Comment: I'm calling that one a bug in SimpleDateFormat ;-) -- I need something that handles the precision...

Comment: [It's documented in the `SimpleDateFormat` javadocs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html), but it may violate the Principle of Least Astonishment.